# Rollback pm2 deploy to specific commit

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, pm2

I would like to know how to use pm2 to "rollback" a recent code change.

Our team's change process requires us to have a "rollback" plan in the case of a problem with a deploy. We normally just document that the rollback plan will be to `git checkout CHANGESET` to go back to the previous version of the code while we fix the issue and test it in dev.

How can I achieve a similar rollback using pm2? Our new-ish deploy process is `pm2 deploy production` and my ecosystem.json is included below. Currently both UAT and production use origin/master as the "ref". I was thinking maybe to use a tag or something, but not sure the best approach. Perhaps I should just continue to do a `git checkout COMMIT` in these rare rollback cases, but looking for other ideas.

```
{
  "apps": [{ blah... }],
  "deploy": {
    "UAT": {
    "user": "USER_HERE",
    "host": ["IP_HERE", "IP_HERE"],
    "ref": "origin/master",
    "repo": "git@github.com:USER/REPO.git",
    "path": "/home/USER/node",
    "post-deploy": "bash ./update.sh"
  },
  "production": {
    "user": "USER_HERE",
    "host": ["IP_HERE", "IP_HERE"],
    "ref": "origin/master",
    "repo": "git@github.com:USER/REPO.git",
    "path": "/home/USER/node",
    "post-deploy": "bash ./update.sh"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool `pm2 deploy` provides the command `revert`. So, you can do:

```
pm2 deploy ecosystem.json revert
```

This "rollback" your app to the previous deploy. You can specify also how many last deployment revert to.

See also the command `[ref]` combined with `list`, `curr` or `prev`:

https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/0.14.7/ADVANCED_README.md#deployment-options

Comment: pm2 deploy ecosystem.json environment revert